# How come a simple PHP array lookup is so slow? Am I doing something wrong here?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have the following function:

```
function percentToColor($percent){
    $minBrightness = 160;
    $maxBrightness = 255;

    // Remainins?
    $brightness = ((($minBrightness-$maxBrightness)/(100-0))*$percent+$maxBrightness);
    $first = (1-($percent/100))*$brightness;
    $second = ($percent/100)*$brightness;

    // Find the influence of the middle color (yellow if 1st and 2nd are red and green)
    $diff = abs($first-$second);
    $influence = ($brightness-$diff)/2;
    $first = intval($first + $influence);
    $second = intval($second + $influence);

    // Convert to HEX, format and return
    $firstHex = str_pad(dechex($first),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $secondHex = str_pad(dechex($second),2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $firstHex . $secondHex . '00';
}
```

This function accepts integers ranging from 0 to 100 and returns the color information for that number. Imagine a progress bar with red at 0 and green at 100. This is what the function does.

So I get the idea: if this function **always** returns the same color for each input (i.e. the colors aren't time/user/session dependent), the better idea would be to create a PHP array with the results, right?

So I rewrite the function:

```
function percentToColorNew($percent){
   $results = array(
      0 => 'ff0000',
      1 => 'fe0500',
      2 => 'fd0a00',
      3 => 'fc0f00',
      // ... continues with 4, 5, up until 100 ...
      99 => '03a000',
      100 => '00a000'
   );
   return $results[$percent];
}
```

And I test it. And the unexpected happens! The new function, which only returns the result from the array of results, takes **double the time** as the original function which has to compute the result every time it's called.

Why is this? Are PHP arrays **this slow**? Is there a faster way of storing the function results to speed up the function? A switch, maybe? If/elseif/else conditions? A different way of working with arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's slow because you are initializing the array each time you call the function.

Set up the array outside of function and it should be much faster. Quick and dirty example:

```
$results = array(
    0 => 'ff0000',
    1 => 'fe0500',
    2 => 'fd0a00',
    3 => 'fc0f00',
    // ... continues with 4, 5, up until 100 ...
    99 => '03a000',
    100 => '00a000'
);

function percentToColorNew($percent){
    global $results;
    return $results[$percent];
}
```

**Edit**: Or even better use the [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) keyword:

```
function percentToColorNew($percent){
    static $results;
    if(!is_array($results)) {
        $results = array ( ... );
    }
    return $results[$percent];
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference between passing the array into the function and making it globally accessible?

Comment: Pass it into the function as a parameter would be the same as making it globally accessible performance-wise.

Comment: using global doesnt makes a sense. OP can initialize array inside the function in this way `static $result;if (null == $result){// code here}`